# How UNARCHIVE a catalog in OBIEE 10?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, obiee

it's possible unarchive a catalog in Oracle Business Intelligence Enterprice Edition, version 10?
I can do it in OBIEE 12, but I dont know how is possible in OBIEE 10.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's the exact same. Archive/Unarchive is the same process no matter if it's 7, 10, 11, 12, or OA.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem is that I can't see 'Unarchive' option on the OBIEE 10. How it's possible? Can you send me please a print screen please?

Comment: If you don't have unarchive that means you don't have sufficient rights to do unarchive.

Comment: Did that resolve your issue?

Comment: Could you else the question please? to other users it looks still unanswered and they can't see that there's a valid response with a solution to the issue. Closing the question helps other users.

Comment: How I can close the question?

Comment: Mark the answer as "Useful"

Comment: I can't cause stack say that: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded"